# XSLT: displaying multiple instances of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm just having a little problem that I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm fairly new to XSLT so I apologize if I'm making a novice mistake or asking a similar question. I just have a simple XML file with movie data and I'm trying to display all the genre's for each movie. Some movies have multiple genre's and some only have one. However when I try to implement my solution I just seem to not get any output at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="movies.xsl"?> 

<movies>

  <movie>
    <title lang="en">Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse</title>
    <poster-url>https://resizing.flixster.com/b5taZMzly27b3UlO8PArsKvP3qM=/fit-in/200x296.2962962962963/v1.bTsxMjg3MjM1MDtqOzE3OTIzOzEyMDA7NjA3Mjs5MDAw</poster-url>
    <trailer src="http://www.intothespiderverse.movie/#trailer"/>
    <release-date><year>2018</year> <month>12</month> <day>14</day></release-date>
    <director>Bob Persichetti</director>
    <director>Peter Ramsey</director>
    <director>Rodney Rotham</director>
    <genre>action</genre>
    <genre>animated</genre>
    <genre>superhero</genre>
    <runtime>100</runtime>
    <actor>Shameik Moore</actor>
    <actor>Hailee Steinfeld</actor>
    <actor>Mahershala Ali</actor>
    <mpaa>
      <rating>PG</rating>
    </mpaa>
    <studio>Sony Pictures</studio>
    <reviews>
    </reviews>
  </movie>
```

and my XSLT  snippet

```
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(genre) > 1">
              Genres:
              <xsl:for-each select="genre">
                <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              Genre:
              <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
```

and this is my entire doc.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <title>Movies Movies Movies</title> 
      </head> 
      <body> 
       <h1>Movies Movies Movies</h1>
       <ul>
         <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
           <li><xsl:value-of select="title"/>
              <br/>
              <img>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                  <xsl:value-of select="poster-url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </img>
              See the
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(trailer)">
                  <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="translate(review,' ','+')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:text>reviews</xsl:text>
                  </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="translate(trailer,' ','+')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:text>trailer</xsl:text>
                  </a>
                  and
                  <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="translate(review,' ','+')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:text>reviews</xsl:text>
                  </a>

                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
              <br/>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(genre) > 1">
                  Genres:
                  <xsl:for-each select="genre">
                    <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  Genre:
                  <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
              <br/>
              Released:  
              <xsl:value-of select="release-date/year"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(release-date/month,'-00')"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(release-date/day,'-00')"/>
           </li>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </ul>

      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my snippet above, I am first confirming whether or not the movie has one or more genre's. If it has more than one, I start a loop and attempt to display all the genre's associated and end the loop. If it only has 1 then its nice and easy and I just display the genre. Its the displaying of multiple genre's that seems to not be working, movies with only one display just fine. I'm thinking it has to do with my `for-each` loop possibly not being in the right place?
 Thanks!

Comment: When you show us only a snippet, we don't know in what context you are. And context is crucial in XSLT.

Comment: I will update this one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you're in the context of `movie`. From this context, the instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="movie/genre">
```

selects nothing.

To process the `genre` elements that are children of the current `movie`, you must do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="genre">
```

---

### Added:

Here you are making the same mistake again:

```
<xsl:for-each select="genre">
```

places you in the context of `genre`. From this context, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
```

selects nothing. `genre` is not a child of itself.  You need to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

(`.` selects the context node.)

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look. After changing the for-each loop to what you mentioned before I still get the same no output for those movies with more than one genre.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: yeah after playing with a little more and thinking back on unix i tried just throwing a '.' in and sure enough haha thank you very much for the insight

Comment: Don't think Unix. Think [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev).